# Class append and remove in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want that whenever I add on button then a class should append and after next click class should remove.
I tried with following code but class not removing in second click here is my code.

```
$("#hide_show_keypad").click(function (e) {
  $(this).addClass("fcurrent").siblings().removeClass("fcurrent");
});
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="btn" id="hide_show_keypad" class="mytest" >
```

Comment: probably `siblings` is the wrong function here?

Comment: on your click you can add an `if` condition  and check if the class exist on the element or not as `if($(this).hasClass('fcurrent')) $(this).removeClass('fcurrent'); else $(this).addClass('fcurrent');`

Comment: in pure JS: `element.classList.toggle('yourclass');`

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggleClass()` to make it work as you want.

```
$("#hide_show_keypad").click(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("fcurrent")
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$("#hide_show_keypad").click(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("fcurrent")
});
```

```css
.fcurrent{color:blue;background-color:yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="btn" id="hide_show_keypad" class="mytest" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('#paragraph').toggleClass("style");
});
```

```css
.style {
  background-color: #000;
  color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="paragraph">This is a sample paragraph.</p>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="btn">Click Me</button>
```